# get only integer values of a string and find second maximum

Tags: java, string, int

Given the String: "1 22a 34 718 u3ou1." The aim is to find only the int values, in this case it's 1 and 34 and 718. I tried it like this:

```
    String str = "1 22a 34 718 u3ou1.";      
    str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", "*"); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim()));
```

The output of this is: [1 22 34 718 3 1].
The output should be: [1 34 718].
Can someone find the bug?

Comment: Don't turn non-numbers into numbers?

Comment: every part which cointais a character + a number should be ignored

Comment: But you aren't doing that.  You're taking parts that contain characters and removing the characters, leaving you no way to distinguish between "real" numbers and things that should be ignored.

Comment: Yeah I know, the thing i don't know is how to delete "22a" for example

Answer (score 0):

Better use split, I believe:

```
private List<int> intArray(string str)
{
 data = str.Split('');
 var result = new List<int>();
 for (var item in data)
 {
   int number=0;
   if (int.TryParse(item,out number))
   {
         result.Add(number);
   }
 }

 return result
}
```

**WARNING:**
1. Have not checked/ tested the code

2.. I have just realized the question was in java, whereas my code is C#

Comment: @progress190, Yes it does...Leave it up to you to convert it to a datatype Ienumerable you prefer

Answer (score 0):

you can try to parse the element, that after splitting up using blankspaces as a delimiter :

```
String str = "1 22a 34 718 u3ou1.";

String[] split = str.split(" +");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String s : split) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            list.add(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            /**
             *
             *do Nothing
             *
             * */
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```